# launching zookeeper server throws to zookeeper properties file

Tags: apache-zookeeper

```
C:\kafka>bin\zookeeper-server-start.sh config\zookeeper.properties
```

It throws me a zookeper.server-start.sh file. I watched youtube tutorial, it does not happen there, it prints some output to shell.

In server-start.sh there is 'exit 1' line , i think this is where it throws me at.

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ];
then
    echo "USAGE: $0 [-daemon] zookeeper.properties"
    exit 1
fi
```

why is zookeper server not starting?

Answer (score 1):

1) You are using Windows, which cannot run `.sh` scripts. You need to use the `windows\` folder and the `.bat` scripts

2) Since you are reading the Bash, you gave an argument, so `$# -lt 1` is false, and you are not getting `exit 1`, which you would check with `echo $?`

I would suggest using Docker Compose or MiniKube to start a Kafka Cluster for local testing.